# What could cause err_connection_reset one one page, and only on mobile devices?

Tags: iis, mobile, coldfusion

We have a ColdFusion Server running on top of IIS.  All of our pages can be viewed in desktop or mobile mode, which just changes some CSS around but shows essentially the same page.  We've run into an odd situation where on one particular page of the site:

- It works fine on a PC viewing the page in desktop mode
- It works fine on a PC viewing the page in mobile mode
- It returns a err_connection_reset on any mobile device viewing the page in mobile mode

What could cause one particular page on a website to show up fine in desktop browsers but return an err_connection_reset on mobile browsers.

This page is not large, and is made up mostly of common components that are used on other pages which are working fine.  No error appears in the server logs (our own, ColdFusions, or IIS').

Google keeps returning me pages about problems with Chrome's data saver mode on pages with 302 redirections.  However, this page does not redirect, and we've experienced this on Chrome, Safari, and the Android browser, on both Android and iOS devices.

Comment: So you can't connect to the website on any browser, and it's only your phone that's affected.... dare I ask, bad WiFi? Not on the right network?

Comment: Try to server up a static HTML page, and see if it can be delivered.

Comment: @Trose We have tried this on 3 different mobile devices, one of which was 400 miles away.  All three were tried with both wifi and just 4g; connection was good.

Comment: @JamesAMohler We can server static HTML pages, and almost all of our dynamic content.  Just one page in particular returns this response.

Comment: @Nicholas is this particular website private? Do you have to be on a certain network or IP range to view it? Is it loading CSS or JS from a source that is no longer valid? Is it possible you're getting infinite redirects? If none of these queries leads you closer to an answer we will have to see some code.

Comment: @Nicholas are you able to recreate the error on desktop with a chrome devtools network tab speed change and/or user-agent spoofing?

Comment: Debug the connection via `chrome://net-export/`. Last time we had connection resets in Chrome, it was actually an issue in Chrome. It resolved itself with an update.

Comment: @DanRoberts That's a great suggestion.  Speed change did not allow me to reproduce on desktop.  I'm not sure how to spoof a user-agent via Chrome dev tools.

Comment: @TRose I don't believe any of those things are the issue, though I'm still wandering if somehow mobile devices are getting a redirect that I'm not seeing any other way.  I'm working through the code now.  Thanks.